# perl6 how to get specific identity of promises?

Tags: promise, identity, raku

I am trying to code 3 echo servers running in promises, but I want to know which promise is doing the echoing. Is there a way to do that?

```
no strict;

for 0 .. 2 -> $index {
    @result[$index] = start {
        $myID = $index; 
        say "======> $myID\n";

        my $rsSocket = IO::Socket::INET.new:
            localhost => 'localhost',
            localport => 1234 + $index,
            listen    => 1;

        while $rsSocket.accept -> $rsConnection {
            say "Promise $myID accepted connection";
            while $rsConnection.recv -> $stuff {
                say "promise $myID Echoing $stuff";
                $rsConnection.print($stuff);
            }
            $rsConnection.close;
        }
    }
}

await @result;
```

The echo servers run ok; tested with "nc";

The problem is `$myID` becomes `2` after the promises are created, and there is no way for me to tell which promise is doing the current echoing. It seems that `$myID` is used by all the promises; is there a way to create variables that are specific to an individual promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really need to have a `$myID` at all. You can just use `$index` in the promise because it has already been scoped to the loop block. Here's a working modification (..with strict on):

```
my @result = do for 0 .. 2 -> $index {
    start {
        say "======> $index\n";

        my $rsSocket = IO::Socket::INET.new:
            localhost => 'localhost',
            localport => 1234 + $index,
            listen    => 1;

        while $rsSocket.accept -> $rsConnection {
            say "Promise $index accepted connection";
            while $rsConnection.recv -> $stuff {
                say "promise $index Echoing $stuff";
                $rsConnection.print($stuff);
            }
            $rsConnection.close;
        }
    }
}

await @result;
```

With that taken care of I feel the urge to point out that using `no strict` seems very unnecessary. Not only does it leave you open to weird scope issues like these, but you gain basically nothing from doing it in your example.

Re-enabling strict on your unmodified code and fixing the two compile errors shows have only saved a total of four keystrokes -- at the expense of however many keys you used typing up your question here.

Answer (score 7):

That's one of the thing you "lose" by going with `no strict`.

What you need is lexical scoping. Using `my` will give you a different variable each time the block (`{ ... }`) is entered.

If you do this:

```
for 0 .. 2 -> $index {
    @result[$index] = start {
        my $myID = $index;
```

Then `$myID` will be local to the `start` block, and each time that block is called, it'll remember its id. So you'll get the correct ID whenever the socket receives data.

Comment: Thank you Ven. You helped me solve the problem. Thanks again ! I will try to use "my" more often :-)

Comment: @lisprogtor: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: There's a little green check under the answer - that's how you "accept"