# perl6 Changes in IO::Socket::INET from last year and broken promises

Tags: sockets, server, promise, raku

When I asked a question last year about promises, my echo server was working (see this link: [perl6 how to get specific identity of promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034367/perl6-how-to-get-specific-identity-of-promises/39034661#39034661) ). However, with the new versions of perl6, my echo server is no longer working.

I guess I can try the example from the perl6 documentation site ( https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Socket::INET ), but I want to find out what mistake I have made in my code. My current level has precluded me from seeing the difference between my codes and the codes on the perl6 documentation site. Please give me a hint; thanks !

```
my @result;

for 0 .. 2 -> $index {
  @result[$index] = start {
    my $myPromiseID = $index; 
    say "======> $myPromiseID\n";

    my $rsSocket = IO::Socket::INET.new:
    localhost => 'localhost',
    localport => 1234 + $index,
    listen    => 1;

    while $rsSocket.accept -> $rsConnection {
        say "Promise $myPromiseID accepted connection";
        while $rsConnection.recv -> $stuff {
        say "Promise $myPromiseID Echoing $stuff";
        $rsConnection.print($stuff);
        }
        $rsConnection.close;
    }
  }
}

await @result;
```

And the error messages are:

```
Tried to get the result of a broken Promise
  in block <unit> at p6EchoMulti.pl line 24

Original exception:
    Nothing given for new socket to connect or bind to
      in block  at p6EchoMulti.pl line 8

Actually thrown at:
  in block  at p6EchoMulti.pl line 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This commit](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/cb9ec035d942c74826bc23c1cf16563771869bcf), which was [announced in the Jan 2017 section of Rakudo's changelog](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/nom/docs/ChangeLog#L950) as "Fixed bug where IPv6 URIs were not parsed correctly" did a lot more that just fix a URI parsing bug. It also completely redid the parameter binding/validation of an `IO::Socket::INET.new` call, and one consequence is it broke your code because the updated code requires that `listen` be an actual `Bool`, not merely coerce to one.

---

The old code (the code on the left of the commit link above) had a simple `method new (*%args is copy)`. This matched your call. The error (`fail "Nothing given for new socket to connect or bind to"`) did not trigger because `1` evaluates to `True` in a boolean context so `%args<host> || %args<listen>` was also `True`. So the rest of the code ran with `listen` set to `1` and it all worked out fine.

Rakudos from 2017.01 have the code on the right at the commit link above. Note how there are now multiple `new` methods (i.e. multiple `multi method new ...` declarations).

The multi(s) intended to handle a call that specifies a `listen` argument is/are of the form `multi method new (..., Bool:D :$listen!, ...)`. Note the `Bool:D`.

A call to `new`, with the `listen` parameter set to **`True`**, matches this multi and works as expected.

But a call with `:listen(1)` will just match the generic `multi method new (*%args)` signature instead. This latter does an unconditional `fail "Nothing given for new socket to connect or bind to";`.

Comment: Thank you raiph !! You have helped me multiple times and I will buy you a coffee if we meet at a perl6 conference :-)

Comment: FWIW, I would classify this as a bug.  The signature should probably be `Bool(Any)`, aka "coerce an `Any` object to a `Bool`.  On the other hand, just specifying `:listen` should be enough, as that is the same as `listen => True`

Comment: @lisprogtor What a nice comment to read. :) In this case I caught your questions just before I went to sleep. But please know that your questions might be answered more quickly and/or helpfully on #perl6, a friendly channel where dropping in just to chat a bit about the solar eclipse or whatever is perfectly cromulent. See https://perl6.org/community/irc or [just click here](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=perl6&nick=lisprogtor) and type "hi". Depending on the time etc. someone will likely reply within a few minutes and you can share a virtual cuppa. :)

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen I pondered what follow up might be appropriate, even if it's just reviewing what back compat guarantees we relay to users and/or core devs. I see carefully applied weak typing (compiler or callee coercion) as a major strength. `Bool(Any)` would silently accept something like `:listen<127.0.0.1>` so that seems too weak to me.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, after some struggling, it seems to have improved if I changed listen=>1 to listen=>True.

Can anyone care to explain why 1 was not evaluated to True, and why it worked before?

Thanks.